# Why is Len Deighton so fond of American English?

Tags: wording-choice, style, len-deighton

I am British and have lived in Britain my entire life. I have never heard anyone refer to an estate car as a “station wagon”. I have never heard anyone refer to a criminal as a “hood”. I have never heard anyone say “wisecrack”. I have never heard anyone say “sure thing”. I have also never heard anyone begin a sentence with “Hell …”, except Ed Miliband during the 2015 election and he was ridiculed for it.

And yet this is the language that the British characters in British writer Len Deighton’s “Game, Set and Match” trilogy use when speaking to other British characters. The narrator also refers to trousers as “pants”, which I have never heard any British person do.

In Berlin Game, the British narrator phones a “Federal Emergency Number”. In London Match, the British narrator tells his British wife that his murdered British subordinate, who worked for the British security services, was punctilious about reciting the “Miranda Warnings.” Nobody in Britain knows what the Miranda Warnings are, but they are what American police recite after they have arrested a suspect.

When I asked a similar question about Berlin Game on Quora, I was told I was reading the American edition. And I was! So I went out and bought the Penguin Classics edition, which, it says in the front, was originally published by Hutchinson. And the Americanisms are still there!

(Somebody on Quora also suggested that FED was the number 333 in the days when phone numbers also had letters and that this took you straight through to Whitehall.)

In all three books, the author repeatedly adopts the American practice of using the past simple tense where traditional British English would use the perfect. It is very, very noticeable, it is on almost every page and I think it is this more even than the American vocabulary and idioms that gives the books such an American flavour.

Can anyone explain this mystery?

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Len_Deighton#Personal_life) that Deighton "left Britain in 1969, and has lived abroad [ever] since".

Comment: FWIW, "hood" is, like a lot of Americanisms, actually archaic English rather than a novel development. Cf. the legend of Robin "Hood", aka Robert of Locksley. Other archaic Americanisms include "fall" for the season, "gotten", and "I guess" (used by Chaucer).

Comment: '_I have also never heard anyone begin a sentence with “Hell …_” you never met my father, born Leicestershire 1920.

Comment: The London FEDeral exchange (01-333 after STD introduction) served key central government functions and was originally a WWII exchange. Nothing to with the 'Federal Government'. Another was the TRAfalgar naval exchange.

Comment: I agree that some of Deighton's later spy series (the Game, Set, Match) series were consciously written for an 'international' readership, I think his early stuff (such as _The Ipcress File_) has a very British flavour, as have (e.g.) _Bomber_ and _SS-GB_.

Comment: 'The narrator also refers to trousers as “pants”, which I have never heard any British person do.' My wife from Lancashire does.

Comment: I made a rather drastic edit to remove what I perceived as ranty-ness in the original question, basically by stripping out the repeated incredulity. Because it was rather drastic I also immediately reverted it: feel free to look at the [revision history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/22412/revisions) and judge for yourself whether you like the difference.

Comment: 'Nobody in Britain knows what the Miranda Warnings are' - except anyone who watches American TV series or crime movies, or who reads American crime novels, and I daresay some UK cops do that. Could be facetious.

Comment: You might be surprised how many UK newspapers report a witness in court 'taking the stand' (which we don't do in the UK), and in TV dramas you sometimes see a barrister leaping up and shouting 'objection!' (which we don't do either. As well as that, you know a UK TV drama's scriptwriters have put flogging the series to the Yanks ahead of authenticity if anyone addresses a plain clothes police officer as (just) 'Detective'.